# Sum of binomial probabilities

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

One of my friends is building a game where the player will get questions from 6 different categories. Each category has a total of 50 questions. A single game consists of answering one question from each category. Questions are selected randomly and independent of previous games. In each game the drawings from each category are also independent.

From observations we have concluded that 
1) either there's a high probability for a player to get the same questions multiple times when e.g. 20 games have been played. 
2) or our random function is not random at all as people do get the same questions regularly.

I have a basic understanding of probability theory and have concluded that we are dealing with multiple binomial distributions (the categories) where the probability for a particular event to occur is p=0.02

If we were dealing with only one category there are many online calculators to put in relevant values for N, k and p http://www.vassarstats.net/textbook/ch5apx.html.

I'm just not sure how to deal with the multiple categories we have.

Does the rule for sums of binomials apply?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Sums_of_binomials

Comment: By induction, if the sum of independent binomials is binomial, then any finite sum is.

Comment: What event are you looking at, exactly? Having, in $n$ games, at least twice the same question (in any of the six categories)?
(in any case, maybe the [multinomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) is better suited to your problem)

Comment: I'm looking for the event where the player will see a question more than one time in any of the categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a variant of the [Birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), played six ways simultaneously.  Playing the game $n$ times, the probability of no repetition is $$\left(\frac{50}{50}\frac{49}{50}\frac{48}{50}\cdots\frac{51-n}{50}\right)^6$$

While the probability of a repetition is $1$  minus that value.

With even $n=4$, the probability of no repetition is about 47%.  With $n=3$, the probability of no repetition is about 69%.  If you want to avoid repetition, you'll need to make these choices non-randomly (i.e. remembering and avoiding previous selections).

Comment: I suspected a probability in that ballpark. Remembering previous selections sounds like a good idea. If you look at it the other way around a really large number of games has to be played to have at least a 99% chance of answering all 50 questions.

Comment: WolframAlpha to the rescue 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+-+%28multiply%28%2851-n%29%2F50%29%2C+n%3D1+to+10%29